# Kendo ui - disabling window dragging

Tags: kendo-ui

Can we disable drag for kendo ui's window http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html?

```
 var wnd1 = $("#window1");
     var wnd2 = $("#window2");
     wnd1.kendoWindow({
         width: "505px",
         height: "315px",
         title: "Window 1",
         iframe: false,
         content: "/Portal/LiveFeeds",
         resizable: false,
         open: function (e) {
             this.wrapper.css({ left: 10 });
             $(this.wrapper).find(".k-window-action").css("visibility", "hidden");
         }
     });
     wnd2.kendoWindow({
         width: "505px",
         height: "315px",
         title: "Window 2",
         iframe: false,
         content: "/Portal/Cases",
         resizable: false,
         open: function (e) {
             this.wrapper.css({ left: 525 });
             $(this.wrapper).find(".k-window-action").css("visibility", "hidden");
         }
     });
```

I was able to hide the X the button at top right - but i am not able to disable the drag event.

Also,

I have tried following:

```
$('#window1').removeData('kendoDraggable');
     $('#window1').removeData('role');
     $('#window1').unbind('mousedown');
     $('#window1').unbind('selectstart');
```

But no luck. Any pointers would be helpful...

Comment: Use kendo window property `Draggable` true or false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the [draggable](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#configuration-draggable) option to `false`.

```
$("#div1").kendoWindow({
  draggable: false
});
```

And here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/OseCeBu/1/edit